# Unable to run flutter command on MS VS code

Tags: windows, flutter, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, flutter-dependencies

I have created a flutter project on VS, and could not run any command through VS code's terminal, I have reinstalled the VS code and still give me this error:

**[image: [X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development. Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/. Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components]**

I have installed it again and don't know why it stays it is not installed!

Any idea how to solve it?

Thank you

Comment: The entire community is dealing with this problem. i suggest try to downgrade for now and be patient.

Comment: are you referring `Visual Studio` error that is shown by `flutter doctor`?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your image; you are using [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), not [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/).

Flutter 2.10 arrives with stable support for building Windows app, [for more](https://www.xda-developers.com/flutter-2-10-windows-apps/).

Therefore, while running `flutter doctor` you are able to see this error. If you've plan to build Windows app, you need to install [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) with `Desktop development with C++`. You need to download and install [Visual studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) if you wish to remove this error.

You can read more about build for window [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70988211/10157127).

Comment: Thanks, it solved the error on the cmd, but the error on the left-hand side of the image still exists in VS code, as I still cannot run a fluter command on VS code terminal, any idea?

Comment: Does it happen for all project ?

Comment: Yes, it does to all projects

Comment: For my case, the issue was with PowerShell terminal, after setting system path and restarting the device solved my issue, you can try opening different  terminal.

Comment: I believe the error is on Powershell/cmd terminal of VS code as well. I have run it throw a separate cmd command and it worked but the embedded cmd, PowerShell terminal on VS code is not working, the connected devices (emulators) weren't also available / connected in the VS code could you throw some light on setting the system Path? is that on the VS code settings? thanks