# Visual studio community necessary for flutter error how to resolve

Tags: flutter, visual-studio

If visual studio community is not necessary for flutter app development, and I dont have enough storage space for downloading it but i have vs code, android studio, git, flutter sdk to get started what should I do to correct this error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Visual studio is necessary for Windows development.

Means you can build Windows app with flutter but to build Windows app you need to install Visual Studio with **Desktop development with c++**.

Let's say you don't want to build Windows app, in this case you can just ignore this warning message.

If you are interested to build Windows app, you need to install Visual Studio.

You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70988211/10157127) where I've described the necessary step for setUp and building Windows app.