# Flutter: Cannot parse result path string

Tags: flutter, dart

Error I am getting:

[image]

When I am trying to build the app (Which is by default app by Flutter), I am facing this problem please someone help me out.

`flutter doctor -v`:

[image]

I also checked the problems but didn't get anything.

I was trying to build the app.

Comment: Can you include how you are building the app? and which device

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows, it is selected windows build by default on VS Code. You can select device on top section for android studio and bottom corner for vs-code.

[image]

and then run the app again.

Also you can use command on terminal like

```
flutter run -d c
```

this will run on chrome(I am using `c` to select chrome).

If you like to build on Windows, you need to install  Desktop development with C++. Check [How to build release version of windows app?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70988211/10157127)

Comment: Hello,i am trying to build this app on my android phone

Comment: does it also happen for counter app?

Comment: Yes it does how to solve it

Comment: try to follow https://stackoverflow.com/q/22583418/10157127