# X Visual Studio is missing necessary components

Tags: flutter

X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop
development with C++" workload, and include these components:
MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
- If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest
C++ CMake tools for Windows
Windows 10 SDK

what is the solution?

what is the solution?

Comment: Did you check  `Desktop development with C++.`  while installing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While installing the VS, make sure to check `Desktop development with C++.`.

[image]

You can follow  [this post 1st part](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70988211/10157127)