# Flutter Doctor shows VSCode not installed, even though its installed in my computer

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

[image]

I am installing flutter for the first time in my laptop. When I ran flutter doctor it shows that VSCode is not installed, even though I have been using it for a while now.

I already have installed VSCode in my laptop but flutter doctor shows that it isn't installed. Ig its got something to do with the path. I'm not rly sure, kindly help....

Comment: visual studio its not the same visual studio code. https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, you can make desktop applications with Flutter as well. Therefore Flutter need Visual Studio and "Desktop Development with C++" tool. Flutter doctor terminal says which version you need to install as well.

Answer (score 0):

The warning message means you didn't installed Visual Studio (not visual-studio code).

You can [download](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) and install visual-studio to  build windows app. Make sure to install Desktop development with C++.

You can follow [this to build Windows app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70988211/10157127)